# Как убить самый тяжёлый процесс в Linux?

Tags: linux, xubuntu

Иногда случаются ситуации, когда я запускаю какое-нибудь толстое приложение (чаще игру) и оно сжирает всю имеющуюся оперативную память (обычно из за утечки или кривого портирования). При этом начинаются лаги, из за которых даже мышь практически перестаёт реагировать и единственный выход - перезагрузка. Своп у меня имеется, но такое чувство, будто от него нет ни малейшего толку. Я назначил сочетание клавиш для вызова диспетчера задач, но когда свободной памяти ноль, он либо вообще не открывается, либо на него невозможно альт-табнуться из за лагов. На самом деле это не большая проблема и такие ситуации происходят не очень часто, но всё же хотелось бы спросить, может кто знает способ одной командой убить процесс, жрущий наибольшее количество памяти? Спасибо.

Comment: Если включен magic sysrq key, то Alt+SysRq+F

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ps axo rss,pid | sort -k1rn | awk 'NR == 1 {print $NF}' | xargs sudo kill -9
```

Comment: как контр-пример - самое жрущее память приложение не всегда тормозит систему.  можно добавить человеческий анализ после запуска `top` и потом уже `pkill -9 name` или `kill -9 pid`. жрущий процесс может быть дочерним и он не помрет.

Comment: можно после awk продолжить пайп с `xargs ps o ppid`

Comment: гнутый ps сам умеет сортировать, так что pid можно обойтись чем-то вроде `ps axo pid= --sort -rss | head -1`